# Check JSON request or not

Tags: json, servlets

How do I check that the request done to the servlet is JSON request or not?

If the request is JSON than the response will be in JSON. Otherwise it will be a web request and response will be a web response.

Comment: Your question is incomprehensible. Try and edit it into a question that can be understood and answered.

Comment: The `Content-Type` header should dictate the content of the body, however `Accept` header should dictate what the client supports. The client could pass you data of `application/json` but require `application/xml` within the Accept.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the Content-Type http header (sent by the client) and check if it is 'application/json'.

```
if ('application/json'.equals(request.getHeader('content-type')) {
    // send json response
} else {
    // send web response
}
```

where `request` is the `HttpServletRequest`.